# Set Link Binary with Libraries path

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a non-standard project layout in Xcode (the previous engineer has custom folder names under the root project instead of what Xcode gives you by default when you start a new Framework project).  I’m trying to pull in a dependency like I’ve done in other projects that have a standard project layout. The moment I drag and drop the framework, any framework like AlamoFire, to the LInk Binary with Libraries Build Phase, it automatically ends up with a build error

```
Framework not found AlamoFire
```

When the compiler tries to link.  Is there a place within Xcode or some xcconfig file that I need to do in order to reset or set an appropriate location to look for the framework when I drag and drop it to the Link Binary with Libraries section of Xcode?

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode Build Settings check the field "Library Search Paths" and "Framework Search Paths".

[image]

Specify the location of libraries or frameworks included within your project within those fields.

Comment: In the link step, after the first Ld command, I can see it does a cd to the srcroot directory which is the non-standard root directory. On other projects I see the srcroot is the main project folder

Comment: Check the "Build Phases" tab and see if there's any type of build scripts that might be changing the directory. Also clean your project, or remove the "Derived Data" so that any cached settings are cleared out.